# Why this RewriteRule for two specific categories doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would appreciate some help to make this Wordpress RewriteRule to work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mywebsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mywebsite/index.php

RewriteRule ^/news-mywebsite/([a-z]+)$ /news-mywebsite/?cat=$1

</IfModule>
```

The url I want to rewrite is this
    http://localhost/mywebsite/news-mywebsite/?cat=news

I'd like to rewrite it as 
    http://localhost/mywebsite/news-mywebsite/news

I tried to search also on google but I can't understand the reason why it is not working htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you check this rule on the the page like this http://htaccess.mwl.be/ ?

Remove slash / . In .htacces a path is without slash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Reorder your rules and remove the leading slash from RewriteRule's pattern :

```
RewriteRule ^news-mywebsite/([a-z]+)$ /news-mywebsite/?cat=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mywebsite/index.php [L]
```

Comment: After I modified the .htaccess as you suggested, it works but in the opposite way, so if I input 'http://localhost/mywebsite/news-mywebsite/news' the output is 'http://localhost/mywebsite/news-mywebsite/?cat=news' that could be a new good starting point...